# How to run tests in IntelliJ idea when some other classes have compilation problems?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Say you have `ClassA`, `ClassATest` and `ClassB`. Assume that `ClassB` has some compilation problems.

Is it possible to run tests in `ClassATest` without IndelliJ complaining about compilation issues in `ClassB`.

Obviously, lets assume that there is no dependencies between `ClassB` and `ClassA'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit the Run configuration for the test case and remove the "Make" entry in the "Before launch" table. This lets you run a test case when your project does not compile.